# Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate ResultSet values to insert query in while loop.
The code snippet is as follows:

```
    String sel="select roll_no from Nursery";
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sel);
    stmt1=con.createStatement();
    int aa;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        aa=rs.getInt(1);
        stmt1.executeUpdate("insert into [Nursery_FirstTerminal_marks](roll_no)values("+aa+")");
        //stmt.close();
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data has been inserted");
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

but the below given error is thrown.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt
```

Can you please suggest how to get out of it..

Comment: Did you try using a second statement for the insert? `stmt2 = con.createStatement()`?

Comment: yes..
second one i.e stmt1 is for inserting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by you have a opening result set open against the same connection. For example, you execute a SqlCommand to select all rows from a table, while the result set is not drained, you try to execute another SqlCommand using the same connection, you will hit this error message.

To solve this, you have two choices:

a. Make sure you read the rest data from the pending result set before you send the next SqlCommand.

b. Use MARS (Multiple Active ResultSet) connection setting to enable multiple active result set in a connection.

Comment: @LGPA: thank you for your response... but i didnt get the second option.. can u please provide with some demo regarding the same

Comment: @LGPA: but i am using SQL server 2000 in this particular program.. and 2000 doesn't support it(MARS)...

Comment: Then you have the only option to close one resultset before using the other!

Comment: thankyou so much... i got the desired output once i used different connection object for stmt1...

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is a possibility to `Dispose` a `Command` object after using it. Autogarbage for the `Command` object is not enough. Try to free it explicitly. Maybe `Statement.close()` is what you need. Just guessing.